# Running multiple Components in one component

Tags: angular, typescript

i am sitting with a bit of a conundrum. I have a component called **Application**.

I also have several other components like **page1**, **page2**, **page3**. all different components with lots of validation and fields that people need to fill in. I want to display all these components one after the other on the **Application** component. When you apply for a new "loan" you get taken to the /application route and there i have a breadcrumb component and all these components **page1**, **page2**, **page3** etc. it could be like personal info, financial info etc.

What is the best way to basically manage where the user is currently (which page to show). Currently in the **application** html im using a switch to switch between showing page1/page2/page3. Then i use a enum to determine where i am as to when i click continue on page1 the enum will say 2 and it will switch to page to. There are many things im not happy with and wondering whether you can help me with a better approach?

Here is my Application HTML :

```
<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-7 ui-md-offset-2">
    <app-application-steps></app-application-steps>
</div>
</div>
<div class="ui-g">
<div class="ui-g-7 ui-md-offset-2" [ngSwitch]="activeStep">
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'getting-started'">
        <app-application-getting-started></app-application-getting-started>
    </div>
    <div *ngSwitchCase="'personal-details'">
        <app-application-personal-details></app-application-personal- 
    details>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
```

each page is its own components as it has different dependencies and lots of validations and code. so its to keep it cleaner.

Any advice or tips would be great.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Andtoniosssss thanks for your answer it made me think about this problem and i ended up using **Child routes**. So each page is a child route of application. Thus you can just you the router to manage whats displaying through a **router-outlet** in your application html.

Here i create the child routes :

```
{path: 'application', component: ApplicationComponent, canActivate [AuthGuardService],
runGuardsAndResolvers: 'always', children: [
     { path: 'getting-started', component: ApplicationGettingStartedComponent },
     { path: 'personal-details', component: ApplicationPersonalDetailsComponent }]
```

And then just a  in the application html template to display these routes.

Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 3):

Use parent component and change child views (pages in your case) -  parent can track the step - this is how steppers work.

It can be done in multiple ways including a set of conditional components

```
<mypage1 *ngIf=step===1></mypage1>
<mypage2 *ngIf=step===2></mypage2>
<mypage3 *ngIf=step===3></mypage3>
```

this is just one possibility.

Comment: What is the advantages of *ngIf over switch? better performance?

Comment: I hope u understood it is just a same concept not duplicate.

Comment: @UnluckyAj Fine by me, but there was no point of duplicating the same concept in 2 answers - I saw that there is 10 mins delay so we didnt wrote that together. Don't worry about it anyway.

Comment: @MADJAR If there is any, it is neglectable.

Comment: should the child views still be like a full component ?